# Multiple external HDDs on PS4

Tags: ps4, psn, hard-drive

Is it possible to connect two external Hard Drives to one PS4? I have a lot of digital games and I just like to keep it installed, but free space on current HDDs (one internal, one external) is quite small.
I think about buying a second HDD case and plug it into another USB socket in the console. Will this solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found answer at least. PS4 can recognize only one external hard disk, so there is no possibility to connect two separate disks and use both of them at the same time.

Buying larger HDD is the only way to extend storage size.

Comment: Just for sake of clarity: what you tried is using two external HD as "extended storage", right? Because I see articles claiming that "Your PS4 will recognise two formatted drives at once - but only one can be used as an external storage location at any one time". This would mean that it should be possible to attach a first HD to be used as "extended storage" to install games, and at the same time a second one that can be used as an usb drive by the media player app or to move screenshots / videos to.